Dynagraph library for a C# .NET option
Is there any way I can create a dynagraph on C# and .NET for a Windows application? I have tried to search ready library but I didn't found any one? And if this is not available then any idea how can we build this graph?
I have a load value on y-axis and position on x-axis.

